# Intellij resolving issues with scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij Idea (v13/v14) for a scala project. IntelliJ is not resolving the classes and showing them in red colour. However, compilation works fine. Because of that, it is not possible to navigate to the other classes from a file. 
Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem? It is making me crazy!!!

Comment: You have installed the scala plugin? V13 or V14? For V13 I would just use sbt gen-idea to set up everything. https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea

Comment: Yes, I am using the scala plugin...I tried with both 13 and 14.. And currently using 14, and getting this issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use IntelliJ 14 and get updated Scala plugin in first place. Then, open the project and invalidate cache.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/cleaning-system-cache.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess either

- The directory containing the source code is not marked as "source root" or
- Intellij runtime memory size is small. Try increasing the values in idea.properties,